# How to randomly select a variable in Python?

Tags: python

```
from random import*
from time import*
print("1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3. Multiplication \n4. Division")
count = int(input("How many question do you want? : "))
question = input("What kind of questions do you want? (Type 1/2/3/4) :")
mark = 0
if question == "1": 
    for x in range(count) :
        a = randint(1,100)
        b = randint(1,500)
        question = input("What is the value of {} + {} : ".format(a,b))               
        if int(question) == (a + b):
            print("You are correct")
            mark = mark+1
        else:
            print("Your answer is wrong")
            print("The correct answer is {}".format(a+b))
if question == "2":
    for x in range(count) : 
        a = randint(1,100)
        b = randint(1,500) 
        if b > a:
            a,b = b,a
            question = input("What is the value of {} - {} : ".format(a,b))
            if int(question) == (a - b): 
                print("You are correct")
                mark = mark + 1
            elif int(question) != (a - b):
                print("Your answer is wrong")
                print("The correct answer is {}".format(a-b))
                mark = mark + 0
elif question == "3":
    for m in range(count) : 
        a = randint(1,100)
        b = randint(1,500) 
        question = input("What is the value of {} ⨯ {} : ".format(a,b))               
        if int(question) == (a * b): 
            print("You are correct")
            mark = mark + 1
        elif int(question) != (a*b):
            print("Your answer is wrong")
            print("The correct answer is {}".format(a*b))
            mark = mark + 0
elif question == "4":
    for m in range(count) : 
        a = randint(1,100)
        b = randint(1,500)
        if b > a:
            a,b = b,a
            question = input("What is the value of {} ÷ {} in integer: ".format(a,b))               
            if int(question) == (a // b): 
                print("You are correct")
            elif int(question) != (a//b):
                print("Your answer is wrong")
                print("The correct answer is {}".format(a//b))  
        
sleep(2)
print("\nYour final mark is {}".format(mark))
```

How to randomly select one of the four operations and change it for every question? It is not necessary to change it but I don't want to display the same type of operation every time.

To clear something, `question = input("What kind of questions do you want? (Type 1/2/3/4) :")`
I write the line just to test if my code is working or not.

Comment: `random.choice()?`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. choice() method (from random lib), receives an iterable where it will randomly retrieve one of them. Do you need exact code example ?

Comment: For future expansion, consider a different approach.  Put each exchange in its own function.  Then make a list of the functions, and use `random.choice` to pick one of the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the random library and pass a list. It will output a random item from the list.

```
import random
random.choice([1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.randint`.

```
import random

question = random.randint(1, 4)   # Returns an integer value between 1 and 4

if question == 1:
    # Do Something
elif question == 2:
    # Do Something, etc.
```